# Loading pre-existing data into Django project

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have a pre-existing db file 'sample.db' in sqlite3 format that I'm trying to import into my Django project.
I've already added it to the settings.py file:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    },
    'sample': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'sample.db',
}
```

I was able to generate the model.py in my application folder using inspectdb.
I have run makemigrations and migrate and everything seems to be fine.

I try to get some data in my views.py: obj = table_name.objects.get(id=1)

Then I start the server: python manage.py runserver, and try to load a page at http://127.0.0.1:8000/

It displays an error message saying:
NameError at /
Name table_name is not defined

What did I miss?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked into Automatic database routing? Check out the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing) and I think it _might_ be useful for you in the long term if you plan to keep using both databases.

Answer (score 0):

As you've added your sample database to your settings as `sample` you need to ensure your queries are using the correct database.

For example `obj = table_name.objects.get(id=1).using('sample')`

The alternative would be to configure your database to be the `default` setting.